# Why does RegisterClientScriptBlock not work after set of instructions in User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My goal is to create asp.net webforms page with one button (User Control), which should create the .xlsx file containing some informations and after creating a file should send alert about succes, or alert saying that error occured. When my method contains only

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
```

everything works fine and site after clicking button is showing alert, but when I insert my code before like this

```
 protected void createXlsx(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                string a = "A";
                int b = 1;
                string c = String.Concat(a.ToString(), b);
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
                worksheet.Cell(c).Value = "Id";
                worksheet.Cell("B1").Value = "Imie Nazwisko";
                worksheet.Cell("C1").Value = "Kwota";
                worksheet.Cell("A2").Value = "";


                // Prepare the response
                HttpResponse httpResponse = Response;
                httpResponse.Clear();
                httpResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                httpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"HelloWorld.xlsx\"");

                // Flush the workbook to the Response.OutputStream
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.WriteTo(httpResponse.OutputStream);
                    memoryStream.Close();
                }

            }
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Created file succesfully')", true);
}
```

The site downloads the xmlx file, but doesnt show alert after clicking button.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this or show message in other way?

Comment: Can you step through the code in createXlsx and make sure there are no exceptions being thrown?

Comment: no exceptions are being thrown

Comment: It's probably because you changed the HTTP response content type to application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet its no longer an HTML document and the script won't be registered

Comment: @Jon Do you know is there a way to change it back? I have tried 
```httpResponse.ContentType = "text/html";```
but still doenst work

Comment: Are you trying to create the xlsx file on the server? Or return it to the browser as a download?

Comment: As far as i know my script is doing both: creating file and returning it to download.

Comment: Is the download working? Does the xlsx file download in the browser? If it does, you can't also have that alert message popup because that script needs to be returned in the html of the browser. You'd need to instead attach some Javascript to the button, have the alert popup there, and have your server code generate and return the XLSX file in the HTTP response

Comment: oh ok, now I understand, thank you very much.

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to write some Javascript to show the alert() when you click the button. Lookup "Show alert in Javascript from ASP.NET WebForm button"